# Overriding template variables for Gradle generation

Tags: unity, android, gradle

I'm using Unity 2020 to build for Android. Unity provides a `mainTemplate.gradle` file, looks a bit like [this](https://github.com/Estimote/Unity3D-Indoor-Example/blob/master/Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle).

As per [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html), there are certain template variables that Unity will fill in when it generates the actual `build.gradle` file.

What the docs don't mention at all is what the logic is behind how these are filled in.
The specific issue I have is that it defaults to a version of the build tools that's too old for a particular entry in my manifest. As such, I'm trying to override `BUILDTOOLS`, but I've not been able to find anything online about either manually overriding an arbitrary template variable, or explicitly setting the Build Tools version.

All the docs say is `SDK Build tools used (for example, 25.0.1).`, completely unhelpfully.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: What version of the Android SDK do you have installed? Does the SDK have a build tools version setting?

Comment: I had two versions of build tools, `28.0.3` which I didn't want, and `30.`something. In the end it just needed a Unity restart to pick up the newer version. So I assume it just ends up choosing whatever's newer in the SDK that's bundled with it.

Comment: Want to write up your solution as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1):

After mucking around with Unity a bit more, I think what happens is that it picks the highest version of the Build Tools component that is installed.

What I didn't realize is that I needed to restart Unity for that to happen.
I also deleted `Temp/gradleOut` for good measure.
So, between these two actions, it eventually started working.

I still haven't got a clue whether it's possible to give those template variables custom values.